# Unmet dependencies because of arm-navigation-experimental

Tags: ros, object-manipulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was trying to install packages like object_manipulation.
But system reported that due to dependency problems, it's marked as broken package.
Does anyone also met this situation before?

Thanks for answering.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-object-manipulation 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-electric-object-manipulation : Depends: ros-electric-arm-navigation-experimental (= 0.4.10-s1332431219~maverick) but 0.4.10-s1332436221~maverick is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30998/unmet-dependencies-because-of-arm-navigation-experimental/) by [Mchaiiann](https://answers.ros.org/users/1388/mchaiiann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2012-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think i had the same problem some weeks ago. If i remember correctly, I had to uninstall the octomap-visualization (octovis).

Try an:
`apt-get install ros-electric-arm-navigation-experimental`
and see what it shows as the next problem.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0